# How do you write a SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) query in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Is there a good way to mimic the behavior of SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT field) in CouchDB?

Imagine we have the following document, which records the time at which a user played a certain song:

```
{
  song_id: "happy birthday",
  user_id: "boris",
  date_played: [2011, 11, 14, 00, 12, 55],
  _id: ...
}
```

I'd like to know the **number of distinct songs ever played by our user "boris"**.  If our user has listened to "happy birthday" 20 times, that song should still contribute just +1 to the overall song count.

In MySQL, I'd simply execute `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT song_id) FROM plays WHERE user_id = "boris"`, but I'm drawing a blank when it comes to writing this in CouchDB.

**Work-Around 1:** If I changed my schema and instead stored all the song-plays inside a single user document for "boris" I could then write a map to emit only distinct values.  However, if I wanted to build something on the scale of last.fm, my fear is that updates would start taking a very long time as the "boris" document size (number of plays) continued to grow.  (There might also be a maximum document size that I would eventually hit).

**Work-Around 2:** I could also write a map function to return *all* of the distinct records, which my python script could sum up itself; but again with hundreds of thousands of distinct songs this would become very slow as well.

What other options am I missing?

Comment: I also considered simply writing this information as a separate document: check to see if (user_id, song_id) already exists, if so update timestamp, otherwise insert new document.  But I was hoping I could use CouchDB's incremental map/reduce updates to build this cache for me instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer was provided by Zachary Zolton on the couchdb mailing list:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201111.mbox/%3CCAGnHtbJ-1-YeLWMLivKzWub98HZY7%2BesnPOHU4pEYgWAsxaszA%40mail.gmail.com%3E

Since you've already got a view that'll give you Boris's 50k unique
songs, you could use a _list function to return the number of rows.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
function() {
 var count = 0;
 while(getRow()) count++;
 return JSON.stringify({count: count});
}
```

If you query this list function, with the same view, key range and
group level, it'll just respond with a bit of JSON, such as: `{"count":"50612"}`

You can read up more here:

- http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/transforming.html
- http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Formatting_with_Show_and_List

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I've interpreted your question correctly;

map:

```
function(doc) {
  emit([doc.user_id, doc.song_id], null);
}
```

reduce:

```
_count
```

query:

```
?startkey=[<userid>]&endkey=[<userid>,{}]&group=true
```

Sample output:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/foo/_design/a/_view/b?group=true&
startkey=[%22foo%22]&endkey=[%22foo%22,{}]

{"rows":[
  {"key":["foo","bar"],"value":2},
  {"key":["foo","bazbar"],"value":1}
]}
```

Comment: This map/reduce would give you (["boris", "happy birthday"], 20), (["boris", "yesterday"], 14), ..., but if the user has listened to 50,000 different songs then this query will return 50,000 different rows.  Basically what I'd like to get back is just the scalar value 50,000.

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling with exactly the same thing (see http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/couchdb-user/201410.mbox/browser)

It just doesn't feel right to get all this output when you just need a scalar value. Even though the list function is a workaround for not getting the full stream of results, this approach feels very odd.

Any alternatives to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of CouchDB (>2.2) you can use the [_approx_count_distinct](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.2.0/ddocs/ddocs.html#_approx_count_distinct) reduce function. Your view would be:

map:

```
function(doc) {
    emit([doc.user_id, doc.song_id], 1);
}
```

reduce:

```
_approx_count_distinct
```

and the query to get the count of song_ids for user "boris" would be:

```
/db/_design/_myddoc/_view/myview?group_level=1&key=["boris"]
```