# Couchdb count unique document field

Tags: couchdb

I store visiting stats in couchdb document and want to display count of unique IP's for an  interval, my design doc  is :

```
{
"unique": {
   "map": "function(doc){ if (doc.type=='stats'){ emit([doc.date], doc.ip); } }"
}
```

I use startKey & endKey to indicate begin and end date, but I can't find how to count unique IP

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get unique values is to have the value you want to be unique in your key, and to group your results.

Then to get a count you need to create a reduce function (although in this particular situation, there's already one built into CouchDB).

So you change your view to something like this:

```
{
  "unique": {
    "map": "function(doc){if(doc.type=='stats'){emit([doc.date, doc.ip], 1);}}"
    "reduce": "_sum"
}
```

(Note that I used your `doc.date`, which assumes that this only has the granularity that you want for finding the counts of unique IPs, and that it will sort in a sensible lexical order, eg. it has values something like "2012-07-01" and not values like "7/1/2012")

Then you can run this query with something like this:

```
http://your.server/your_db/_design/your_views/_view/unique?startkey=["2012-07"]&endkey=["2012-08"]&group=true
```

(You'll need to url encode the `[]"`s unless you're using your browser (which does it for you))

Comment: View shows documents grouped by IP repetition but I need to get count of IP's by date, already tried _count with no success

Comment: Your comment sounds like you haven't actually added the reduce.  You need to read/try what I wrote closer.  I copied it straight from a working view doing precisely what you asked for.  A count of unique values per day.

Comment: Your view show something like this :
`{"rows":[
{"key":["2012-07-02","127.0.0.1"],"value":2},
{"key":["2012-07-02","127.0.0.6"],"value":1}
]}`

But I need count of unique IPs

Comment: Oh, I see what you want.  Not a count of each IP, but a count of all the unique IPs.  Just read the JSON in and do a `rows.length`

Comment: Maybe a solution but I expect to have 5k-8k of users daily.
I tried to do a custom reduce solution :
`function(keys, values,rereduce) {
  
   var count = 0;
   var uniq_ip = {};
   values.forEach(function(ip) {
   if (uniq_ip[ip] == undefined) {
 uniq_ip[ip]=1;
 count++;
}
});
   return count;
}`

With map :

`function(doc){ if (doc.type=='stats'){ 
 emit([doc.date,doc.ip], doc.ip); 
} }`

Comment: That will not work.  View functions must be side-effect free because the view indexes are incrementally updated as your data changes, so CouchDB re-runs view functions on subsets of your data in various nodes of the b-tree indexes it has internally.  So during those incremental executions your `uniq_ip` hash will only contain the IPs in a small subset of your data.

Comment: There is actually a solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132739/how-do-you-write-a-select-countdistinct-field-query-in-couchdb) using a list function, but that actually does precisely what I recommended, just getting the length of the rows array.  I think it would actually be slower.  It would be less data transfer for you though - so might be what you're after.