# Getting total count of mapped/reduced records in CouchDB

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb, couchdb-futon

The data in couch has a record for each contact type as follows.

```
[{
  "_id":"1"
  "contact_type":"AA"
  "contact_email" : "userA@domain.com"
},{
  "_id":"2"
  "contact_type":"BB"
  "contact_email" : "userA@domain.com"
},{
  "_id":"3"
  "contact_type":"CC"
  "contact_email" : "userA@domain.com"
},{
  "_id":"4"
  "contact_type":"AA"
  "contact_email" : "userB@domain.com"
},
{
  "_id":"5"
  "contact_type":"BB"
  "contact_email" : "userB@domain.com"
}]
```

> Records 1,2,3 represent contact with the email userA@domain.com while
>   records 4 and 5 represent contact with an email userB@domain.com.

My task is to build a query to get the total amount of unique contacts (2 in this case) but I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Currently, I have a map function with _count reduce

```
function(doc){
  emit(doc.emailAddress, 1);
}
```

which returns

```
{
  "rows":
    {
      "key" : "userA@domain.com",
      "value" : 3
    },
    {
      "key" : "userA@domain.com",
      "value" : 2
    }
}
```

However, what I need is the total amount of those records above, i.e. something like

```
{
  "total" : 2
}
```

(*Note: the database is large so looping through the mapped/reduced view to count the records is not an option*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can use the approach described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132739/how-do-you-write-a-select-countdistinct-field-query-in-couchdb)

1.- Define a view as you described in your question (i.e. named "emails")

2.- Define a list function (in my example named "count")

```
function(head,req){
 var count = 0;
 while(getRow()) count++;
 return JSON.stringify({total: count});
}
```

Assuming your design doc is named "users", you can transform the view result using the list function with this URL.

```
http://.../db/_design/users/_list/count/emails?group=true
```

You should get the distinct value count as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Set the reduce function to _count and it should do what you want.

In your case you can also use _sum.